# Wrong character encoding in POST request

Tags: php, android, mysql, http, post

I need to store string "Wiadmość" in MySQL database, but the updated record has value "WiadomoÅ›Ä‡". Here's my POST method

```
private static String post(String endpoint, List<NameValuePair> params) throws IOException
{
  HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
  HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(endpoint);
  String responseBody="NULL RESPONSE";

      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
      ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
      responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
return responseBody;
}
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["did"]) && isset($_POST["dpw"]) && isset($_POST["msg"])) {
$did = $_POST["did"];
$dpw = $_POST["dpw"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
// Store user details in db
include_once './db_functions.php';

$db = new DB_Functions();

$res = $db->storeMessage($did, $dpw, $msg);

if ($res)
echo "1";
else
echo "0";
echo $msg;
} else {
// user details missing
}
?>
```

By Wireshark I catured the echo response from php script ($msg value) and it looks this "1Wiadomo\305\233\304\207".
String sent by android device also captured by wireshark looks like this : "msg=Wiadomo%C5%9B%C4%87".
String obtained from "List NameValuePair params" looks correctly.
Database encoding is correct (utf8_general_ci), and by manual record edit it stores correct data.

DB_Connect.php

```
class DB_Connect {

// constructor
function __construct() {

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
}

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_set_charset("utf8",$con);
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $con;
}

// Closing database connection
public function close() {
    mysql_close();
}

} 
?>
```

Comment: Are you correctly setting the character set of the connection between PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Where do you see the "incorrect" string exactly? HTML, PHP, MySQL view? Make sure you output your html with utf8, submit forms with utf8, have your database connected with utf8 and columns set to utf8 ... and even saved your php (etc.) files in utf8.

Comment: Have you set your `meta` tag in your `head` to indicate your page is UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution would be to set the use the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php to set the character set on the mysql connection. Alternatively you can use a query `set names utf8;` on the mysql connection before hand.

Comment: Note that `mysql_set_charset()` is specific to ext/mysql (which one ought not to be using anymore).  Other APIs have their equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_encode()` your inputs before adding them to the database.

Comment: this causes that the result string looks like this "WiadomoÅ›Ä‡Å›Ä‡"

Comment: sounds like you need to change the collation in your mysql table.